# como borrar todas las letras de un string y dejar solo los números?

Tags: java

tengo un jComboBox que devuelve un string siempre con la misma estructura pero que los datos varían según lo que ingresa el usuario: nombreDelUsuario: DnIDelUsuario  ej:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito es de ese string quedarme solo con el dni y el resto borrarlo

desde ya muchas gracias a quienes se tomen el tiempo en ayudarme

Comment: Hola nicolas, trata de agregar lo que hayas investigado o intentado te aseguro que de  esta forma aprenderás mas, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

Comment: me sirvió muchas gracias !

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es usar un REGEX y usando el método `replace()`:

```
 String dniInicial = "12345nicolas gigena67890";

 String dni = dniInicial.replaceAll("\\D+","")
```

El valor obtenido seria : `1234567890`

---

Otra es usar un método que obtiene los elementos que son dígitos, mediante el método `Character.isDigit()` :

```
public static String removechar(String string, Character element) {
    char[] arr = string.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<Character> arrlist = new ArrayList<Character>();
    ArrayList<Character> finalList = new ArrayList<Character>();

    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        arrlist.add(((Character) arr[i]));
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < arrlist.size() ; j++) {
        if(Character.isDigit(arrlist.get(j))){
            System.out.println("Es digito :" + arrlist.get(j));
            finalList.add(arrlist.get(j));
        }else{
            System.out.println("NO es digito :" +arrlist.get(j));
        }
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(finalList.size());        
    for (Character k : finalList) {
        result.append(k);
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

usando el método anterior

```
 String dniInicial = "12345nicolas gigena67890";    
 String dni = removechar(dniInicial , Character.MIN_VALUE);
```

El valor obtenido seria : `1234567890`